# Migrating SVN repositories issues + SVN can't create directory

Tags: migration, svn

I had to reformat my PC from scratch. I restored my backup data, including a directory containing SVN repositories and a directory containing check-outs of those repositories. These check-outs contain work that has not been checked-in yet.

When I try to check-in, SVN dumps error messages. I could trace it to the fact that I have changed the location of these directories from:

```
C:/Users/J%C3%A9r%C3%B4me/Documents/Java/Repositories/...
C:/Users/J%C3%A9r%C3%B4me/Documents/Java/CheckOut/...
```

to:

```
C:/Users/JVerstry/Documents/Java/Repositories/...
C:/Users/JVerstry/Documents/Java/CheckOut/...
```

Yes, I choose a different user account name when re-installing my machine. And yes, svn does not manage to fall back on its feet.

How can I solve this issue? I checked the content of files located in `.svn` hidden repositories and it seems like they contain lines such as:

```
file:///C:/Users/J%C3%A9r%C3%B4me/Documents/Java/Repositories/...
```

I was thinking may be I could use a tool to scan those files and replace `J%C3%A9r%C3%B4me` with `JVerstry`. Is such a tool available for Windows 7? And is this a good idea?

**EDIT**

I turns out that my issues are deeper than described above. Some of my `.svn` directories seem corrupted + some directories seem to be locked and cannot be unlocked (SVN dumps error messages...) + some directories are missing in the `/db` directory of every repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the idea of modifying `J%C3%A9r%C3%B4me` to `JVerstry`, but it did not work. However, I found a solution to all my issues.

For each repository:

1. I *checked-out* the content of the repository into a `/NewCheckOut` directory.
2. I created a patch from my existing `/CheckOut` directory to capture all modifications made on existing files, but not files added since last check-out.
3. I applied the patch to my `/NewCheckOut` directory. I had to make one manual intervention to solve some incompatibility issue.
4. When trying to check-in `/NewCheckOut`, I face the issue mentioned [here](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/01/svn-cant-create-directory-error.html). I created the missing directories in `/db`. The check-in went fine after.
5. In order to retrieve *added files*, I *exported* the content of my existing `/CheckOut` directory in `/ExportCheckOut`. This gets rid of the corrupted `/.svn`.
6. I used Windows explorer to copy all content of `/ExportCheckOut` in `/NewCheckOut`.
7. I made sure code compiled fine.
8. I checked-in `/NewCheckOut` again.

Problem solved. I don't exactly know what caused it though...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to solve that by using svn switch to tell Subversion that you are talking to "another" repo. --relocate may be needed in this scenario, I think.

Comment: The problem is that svn complains that there are locks, and it won't remove them, even with clean-up